# Indexing material that appears inside \afterpage

Tags: indexing, afterpage

My document contains some landscape-orientation tables that I set inside an `\afterpage` command.  When I try to index material that appears inside these tables, I sometimes end up with duplicate index entry headings.  From looking at the `.idx` file, this is apparently because `\afterpage` rewrites the argument of my `\index` commands by removing `\protect` commands and introducing extraneous spaces.  Here is a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{afterpage,makeidx}\makeindex

% For indexing material in tables
\newcommand{\tab}[1]{\emph{#1}}

% Stand-in example for a fragile command that needs \protection
\newcommand\fragilecmd{FragileCommand}

\begin{document}
\fragilecmd\index{FragileCommand@\protect\fragilecmd}
\fragilecmd-x\index{FragileCommand@\protect\fragilecmd!\protect\fragilecmd-x}
\afterpage{
\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{l}
    \fragilecmd \\
    \fragilecmd-x \\
  \end{tabular}
  \index{FragileCommand@\protect\fragilecmd|tab}
  \index{FragileCommand@\protect\fragilecmd!\protect\fragilecmd-x|tab}
\end{table}
}
\newpage\printindex
\end{document}
```

I expect the resulting index to look as follows:

> **Index**
>
> FragileCommand, 1, *2*
>
> > FragileCommand-x, 1, *2*

However, it instead looks like this:

> **Index**
>
> FragileCommand, *2*
>
> > FragileCommand-x, *2*
>
> FragileCommand, 1
>
> > FragileCommand-x, 1

And here is the contents of the `.idx` file produced by makeindex:

```
\indexentry{FragileCommand@\protect\fragilecmd}{1}
\indexentry{FragileCommand@\protect\fragilecmd!\protect\fragilecmd-x}{1}
\indexentry{FragileCommand@\fragilecmd |tab}{2}
\indexentry{FragileCommand@\fragilecmd !\fragilecmd -x|tab}{2}
```

How can I properly index such entries appearing in `\afterpage`?

Comment: This is nothing to do with afterpage, `\index` reads its argument verbatim but like all verb things that does not work in the argument of another command. if uou use `\newcommand\myindex[1]{\index{#1}}` then use `\myindex` instead of `index` you will disable the verb feature and the form written to the idx file will match

Comment: by the way you are missing lots of `%` you have `\end{tabular} <space> \index{} <space> \index{}` so could get spurious line breaks at those spaces if the table is wide enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `\protect` in the first two cases: `\index` at the top level (not inside the argument to a macro) uses a verbatim mode for writing the entries in the `.idx` file.

What you need instead is `\string` in the entries within `\afterpage`, because `\index` now *is* in the argument to another command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{afterpage,makeidx}\makeindex

% For indexing material in tables
\newcommand{\tab}[1]{\emph{#1}}

% Stand-in example for a fragile command that needs \protection
\newcommand\fragilecmd{FragileCommand}

\begin{document}
\fragilecmd\index{FragileCommand@\fragilecmd}
\fragilecmd-x\index{FragileCommand@\fragilecmd!\fragilecmd-x}
\afterpage{%
\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{l}
    \fragilecmd \\
    \fragilecmd-x \\
  \end{tabular}%
  \index{FragileCommand@\string\fragilecmd|tab}%
  \index{FragileCommand@\string\fragilecmd!\string\fragilecmd-x|tab}%
\end{table}%
}
\newpage\printindex
\end{document}
```

This is what appears in the `.idx` file:

```
\indexentry{FragileCommand@\fragilecmd}{1}
\indexentry{FragileCommand@\fragilecmd!\fragilecmd-x}{1}
\indexentry{FragileCommand@\fragilecmd|tab}{2}
\indexentry{FragileCommand@\fragilecmd!\fragilecmd-x|tab}{2}
```

and so the index will be as expected

[image]

Comment: This works, except that `\string` gobbles spaces after the command it escapes.  So `\index{Foo Bar@\foo \bar}` produces a different index entry than `\index{Foo Bar@\string\foo \string\bar}`.  Can your answer be adapted to address this?